# How to create a chat room and add users into the room in openfire using PHP

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire, muc

I'm new to XMPP server. I want to make multi user chat application.

I have installed Openfire and one to one chat is working properly but i'm not able create a conference(chat) room and add users into the room using PHP for multi user chat.

Although I have installed MUC service plugin available in openfire but I dont know how to implement the MUC Service REST/HTTP with PHP.

Can anybody have some sample PHP script for MUC service to create chat room and adding users into the chat room?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have the same question anybody help me. I will pay 2000 USD

Answer (score 1):

Base on help information:

> Basic HTTP Authentication
>
> All REST Endpoint are secured by Basic HTTP Authentication.
>
> To access the endpoints is that required to send the Username and
>   Password of a Openfire Admin account in your header request.
>
> E.g. Header: Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU= (username: admin /
>   password: 12345)
>
> Example for Jersey Client
>
> Client c = Client.create();  c.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(user,
>   password));
>
> POST /mucservice/chatrooms
>        Endpoint to create a new chat room.
>
> Payload: Chatroom  Return value: HTTP status 201 (Created)
>
> Possible parameters
>
> Parameter Parameter Type  Description Default value
>   servicename   @QueryParam The name of the Group Chat Service  conference
>   Examples
>
> Header: Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU=
>
> Header: Content-Type: application/xml
>
> POST http://example.org:9090/plugins/mucservice/chatrooms
>
> Payload Example 1 (required parameters):
>
> global-1
>       global
>       Global Chat Room

PHP code will be (tested with MUCservice version 0.2.3 Openfire 3.10.0):

```
function createRoom($naturalName, $roomName, $description) {
    $url = "http://localhost:9090/plugins/mucservice/chatrooms";
    $data = "<chatRoom>
                <naturalName>$naturalName</naturalName>
                <roomName>$roomName</roomName>
                <description>$description</description>
            </chatRoom>";
    $username = "admin";
    $password = "12345";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, "9090");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                     array('Content-Type: application/xml',
                           'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode("$username:$password")));
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "code " . $code;
    print_r($res);
    curl_close($ch);
}

createRoom("room", "room", "room");
```

Comment: Do i need to install plugin chatrooms on my xmpp ?  i mean you've set url something  http://localhost:9090/plugins/mucservice/chatrooms  Please help! :)

Comment: I've tried  your code it returns code 0 what i am doing wrong here? as per my knowledge 0 code means curl can't find the server i'm looking for! :( but again i am passing right url! to confirm i have created user successfully from that particular url.

Comment: In my openfire admin under MUC Service shows (Deprecated) Please use the REST API Plugin. MUC administration over REST Interface.

Comment: hmmm, I used Muc service version 0.2.3 for openfire 3.10.0. Which version MUC service are you using?

Comment: I do use Muc version 0.2.3 and Openfire 3.10.2 but at the plugin section Muc service description it says : (Deprecated) Please use the REST API Plugin. MUC administration over REST Interface so i've searched https://community.igniterealtime.org/blogs/ignite/2015/02/06/introducing-restapi-plugin-for-openfire but again! it shows deprecated!